# What type should be used for multiple categories field in mysql

Tags: mysql

**I want to store categories of a item in mysql db**. And what data type should I use for this field. Note that one item can have multiple categories. A quick ( dirty? unsure ) method is using INT in bitwise. But INT is 32-bit long, which means I can only assign 32 categories at most for a item. For now, it's not a problem. But I am not sure what to do if, say, at some day I have to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should have a different table that stores item - category relations.

Comment: you need a many to many relantionship, if you cannot do this you can alter the bitwise field from `Int` to `BIGINT` => 64 categories

Comment: @user1615903 So I need a new tbl to store this relationship. And what's the structure, should I create fields for all possible categories as the attribute of items?

Comment: [Raphael Althaus's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16687216/1615903) pretty much explains the table structure.

Comment: @Stephan Is it something like a two fields tbl. Say, the first field is "itemId", the second is "category". And I insert like "1, 0" "1, 13" "1, 34" "2, 3" etc. ?

Comment: @zoujyjs are you referring to the fact that you can use a bit map to keep the categories?

Answer (score 1):

something like that

```
table item
field item_id (int) => PK
item_name
etc

table category
field cat_id (int) => PK
field cat_name
etc

//a table to manage many to many relationship
table item_category
field item_id (int)  => FK to item.item_id
field cat_id (int) => FK to category.cat_id
//PK is item_id, cat_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Risking a downvote, but my suggestion is - don't use a relational database to store this type of 'flexible' structure; not that you can't - you can (as in Raphael's answer); but you'll have to deal with monstrous `JOIN`s across multiple tables just to display a single page.

- Do you want to filter by categories?
- Do you want to search by categories?
- Do you want to show "most popular" categories?
- Do you want to create a "tag cloud"?

For all those, you need a *key/value store* - a database optimized for this sort of stuff. redis, memcached, even couchbase can be used for this.

The idea is simple:

1. You store the salient properties of your item in your relational database. This is stuff that won't change; for example, each item will have a name, a stock code, a unique identifier, etc.
2. For any other property that can be flexible per-type of item (for example, shirts will have sizes, colors; computers will have hard disk type, memory, etc.) you store them as key/value pairs. You link each of the key value pairs to the item by its unique id.

Since the k/v data store is optimized for flexible data searches and fast queries across them, you are not restricted by the number or type of properties you can store for each product. You can add/delete/reset to your heart's desires all without having to disturb your core database structure.

This paradigm is common so some databases even provide native types for this. postgresql for example, has a [`JSON` column type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/functions-json.html).